# Retorno json api no ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, ionic3

Estou com o seguinte problema , estou utlizando uma `api` ,que eu criei , quando eu uso o **método** find eu passo um `email` e ele me retorna se encontrou o e `email` e `senha`

**Método**

```
 buscarEmail(){
    this.webservice.findConta(this.email).subscribe(data=>  {
        this.listaContas = data ;
        console.log(this.listaContas);

});
```

**console.log**

```
[Array(1)] 0 :
Array(1) 0:
{id: 7, email: "Ivan@mail.com", senha: "4154512"}
length:1
```

*mas quando eu tento acessar*

**Método**

```
buscarEmail(){
    this.webservice.findConta(this.email).subscribe(data=>  {
        this.listaContas = data ;
        console.log(this.listaContas.email); //alteirei para .email

});
```

**console.log**

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está justamente na sua alteração:

```
    buscarEmail(){
this.webservice.findConta(this.email).subscribe(data=>  {
    this.listaContas = data ;
    console.log(this.listaContas.email); //alteirei para .email
});
```

Você colocou o nome de `this.listaContas` e está jogando o data para dentro dele e não para `this.listaContas.email`. Quando você tenta acessar a propriedade `this.listaContas.email` não existe.

Tente assim:

```
buscarEmail(){
this.webservice.findConta(this.email).subscribe(data=>  {
    this.listaContas.email = data ;
    console.log(this.listaContas.email); //alteirei para .email
});
```